# Product Review and Rating

Tags: product, review, ratings

What is the best way to get a collection of product reviews, and retrieve the name and rating number from this collection?

thx.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [How to get product rating and review in magento](http://rashidmagento.blogspot.com/p/how-to-get-product-rating-and-review-in.html)

```
$productId = $product->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
                ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes();
/**
* Getting average of ratings/reviews
*/
$avg = 0;
$ratings = array();
if (count($reviews) > 0) {
   foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
      foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
        $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
           ..
```

Comment: That returns the averaged sum of all ratings.  I want to get the individual rating of a single review.

Comment: Did you try $review->getData(); or $vote->getData()?